# Usage of "For the" in sentence starting

Tags: grammar, psychology, prepositions

"For the dream proves on psychological investigations to be the first of the series of abnormal psychic formation".

Can anyone please help me understand the meaning the above sentence implies?

I think the meaning is "psychological investigations proves dream is the first of the series of abnormal psychic formation".

Am I correct?

Comment: This might not hold true in "psychological parlance" but in mine: “Prove(s) to be” = “turn(s) out to be,” “the dream” = “dreams,” and “**the** series” = “**a** series”; giving: “According to/Based on/(or for cynics)/If you [can] believe psychological investigations, it turns out that dreams are the first of/in a series of abnormal psychic formation.”

Comment: What does the dictionary say for *for*? Does it say that it can mean *because*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"For" in this context means ["because"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Conjunction). A paraphrase of your sentence would be:

> After psychological investigations, it is discovered that the dream is the first of the series of abnormal psychic formations.

Comment: Unfortunately, the (plausible) conjecture that *for* means because isn't reflected in the paraphrase.   If *for* means because here, the sentence would be an answer to a "why" question, say "Why do we do dream interpretation at the start of treatment?"  Does "the dream" mean a particular dream or does it mean "the dream state"?  *On* would be idiomatic with singular "investigation."; "in" or "during" for the plural.  *Series* expects a plural object with the *of* -- "formations."  We need more context for a definitive judgment.